# Checking that an iframe contents changes in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, iframe

I am doing something like this:

```
var samePath = "http://www.example.com";

function iframeLoaded(){
    console.log( iframe.contentDocument.innerHTML );
    iframe.src = samePath;
}
iframe.onload = loaded;
```

Unfortunately, this is really slow: the loading process waits that everything attached to the iframe has actually loaded.

Now:

- I cannot use `DOMContentLoaded`, because once I've set iframe.src, it takes "a little while" for Chrome to create a new `iframe.contentDocument` object, and I cannot reliably attach events to it (unless I start polling... which would be even worse).
- I cannot use `DOMFrameContentLoaded` because Chrome doesn't fire it (ugh): https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33604 It's a bug, but nobody has tackled it for nearly a year
- I cannot use `Object.defineProperty()` on `iframe.contentWindow.document` (javascript won't allow it)
- I don't think polling for iframe.contentWindow.document is a sane way to go about it (is it?)

So... what is there a way I didn't think about that I could/should follow?

The only other way I thought about is to make an AJAX call and then do document.write() on the iframe. But then, *all* links to Javascript, CSS etc. will be broken -- unless you can point out a way to make it work without using RegExp...?

NOTE: Please ignore ANY comments about iframe security etc., as that is *not* the point of this question. Also, I am not able to change the viewed page...

Comment: Is adding code to the page being viewed in the iframe an option? If so you can call `parent.loaded()` function from within the iframe when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires.

Comment: Nope sorry. Question updated...

Comment: Unfortunately the best you can do is to use a setInterval to poll the iframe to see if `iframe.contentDocument.body` exists or  `iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML` has the content you are expecting.